# jQuery Ajax JSON response with <img /> tag breaks in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xhtml

I'm having a problem with IE (I'm testing in IE9, but I believe it will behave the same way in the previous versions as well).

The response I'm sending from PHP is as follow:

```
{"success":true,"content":"<img src=\"\/media\/page\/1528484482.jpg\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\" alt=\"1528484482.jpg\" \/>"}
```

It works absolutely fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera etc. - but it doesn't work in IE.
The response is an empty object.

When I change the response to the following it works fine - the only difference is the forward slash before the closing of the img tag:

```
{"success":true,"content":"<img src=\"\/media\/page\/1528484482.jpg\" width=\"140\" height=\"140\" alt=\"1528484482.jpg\">"}
```

Is there any way of parsing the 'content' response so that it doesn't break in IE?

Comment: Why not just not include the closing slash? You did say that fixes the problem right?

Comment: That's correct - if there's no closing slash there's no problem.

Comment: Also, i don't think you need to escape all those slashes, though it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: They are all escaped as you can see above - this is the actual response from php using json_encode().

Comment: slap a `str_replace('\/','')` on it after you `json_encode()`?

Comment: but that's actually going to remove the closing slash - in which case I can also remove it from the response. I thought that there might be some fix for IE, but I've been searching around for the answer and I think my best option will be to create image in js - just send the response with all attributes of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is an advice, more than a solution)
Separate presentation layers (js/html [how]) and the domain layers (php [what]).

Domain layer decides what data to return.
Presentation layer decides how the data will be presented.

Return the image path, and make the presentation layer decide how to show the image to the user.

---

Now the solution of your problem would be on the declaration of the doctype. 
I suppose the problem is for not declaring the doctype and IE is taking XHMTL as its default doctype.
In XHTML the  tag must be properly closed. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

The rest of the browsers takes HTML5, i suppose, and it doesn't require a closing tag on the image.

Comment: Hi Tomas - I very much appreciate your advice. Sometimes however it is difficult to return large blocks of code as separate pieces to javascript. I'm using HTML5, but I like using the slash closing tags - since it's ok in HTML5 to use both. I believe that IE leaves me no choice and to use tags without the closing slash.